# C program for NIOS II running in wrong sequence

Tags: c, eclipse, sequence, intel-fpga, nios

I'm writing a code in C language for my NIOS II processor. 
I'm using Ecplipse that making me crazy! 
It stuck a lot!!

This part of code should read register using SPI, change the data, write it back and then read it again for a validation.

So the sequence should be SPIread->SPIwrite->SPIread.
When I run it i get SPIread->SPIread->SPIwrite.

The code example:

```
alt_u32 SpiRead(alt_u8 spiNbytes, alt_u8 spiReg)
{
    IOWR_32DIRECT(NRF24_SPI_BASE, 0, 0x1f & spiReg);    //set register 
    IOWR_8DIRECT(NRF24_SPI_BASE, 8, 0x07 & spiNbytes);  //Start SPI read
    return IORD_32DIRECT(NRF24_SPI_BASE, 12);           //return the data
}

void SpiWrite(alt_u32 data,alt_u8 spiNbytes,alt_u8 spiReg)
{
    spiReg = 0x1F & spiReg;
    spiReg = 0x20 | spiReg;
    data = data<<8;
    IOWR_32DIRECT(NRF24_SPI_BASE, 0, data | spiReg); //set register
    IOWR_8DIRECT(NRF24_SPI_BASE, 8, 0x07 & spiNbytes); //begin write SPI
}


int main(void) 
{
 alt_u32 dat = 0;
 dat = SpiRead(1, 0x06); //read spi

 dat = ((dat>>8) & 0x000000f8) | 0x00000005; //change data
 SpiWrite(dat, 1, 0x06);  //write data back

 dat = SpiRead(1, 0x06); //read data to validate

 while (1)  {   }  //stay here forever

 return 0;
}
```

If I remove the while loop I get 4 times SPIread and after that 2 times SPIwrite. Each little change may change everything...
My program is 6Kbytes now and I have 18Kbytes dedicated memory (OnChipMemory).

What is wrong, please help! 
Dmitry.

Comment: How are you determining that a read or write operation in being performed?  Are you taking into account the fact that SPI is always an *exchange* of data, read and write occurring at the same time, and that a dedicated "read" or "write" is simply a transaction in which some of the data going in one direction is ignored (and perhaps has an unexpected value)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention it. I check the data with oscilloscope, it's connected to all SPI lines.   SPI is active only when i perform Read or Write actions. I don't use them simultaneously, only separately Read and Write.

Comment: How do you tell a read from a write?  Again, unless you have the bidirectional variation they always coincide, even if some of the time MISO or MOSI is a don't care.  The mere fact of it being a don't care *does not* mean it will not be driven with some pattern of data.

Comment: SPI is working fine, it had been tested on another project. The problem is in C program or Eclipse itself.

Comment: And again, how are you able to determine that the wrong operations are performed?  You are yet to post a credible explanation.  What is your **exact** result that leads to your conclusion?

Comment: I see the output on my oscilloscope, I see when it performs Read or Write operations. For example, today morning it performs only one Read operation and nothing else.

Comment: You have never answered how you distinguish a read from a write on the scope.

Comment: I'm controlling nRF24 IC, it's 16bit SPI communication. 
First byte in MOSI it's an address, the highest bit is a read/rite flag. When it's read, second byte in MISO it's an actual read data, if it's write, the second byte of MOSI is the write data.

Comment: Anyway, I have solved the problem by changing the SPI block to another one and started to use another library. Now it seems to work fine.